# 3d density of population visualisation on map Python

Tags: python, visualization

I am looking for Python module, in which I could create 3d visualization of population density on map. To create 3d plot like this:

[image]

Comment: This solution may give you some ideas for Python, [GeoHistogram3D](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/1399039).